# javascript when page load ask user audio permission

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: permission]

I have a site need auto play sound notification.

I need to trigger browser sound permission, anyone know how to use javascript to trigger this?

```
new Audio('notification.mp3').play();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  navigator.getUserMedia =
      navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.msGetUserMedia

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia(
        {  audio: true },
        function onSuccess(stream) {
            // go play
        },
        function onError(error) {
          
        }
      )
    } else {
      
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AudioContext()` interface to play it.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var url = '<AUDIO_URL>.mp3';
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext; //fix up prefixing
    var context = new AudioContext(); //context
    var source = context.createBufferSource(); //source node
    source.connect(context.destination); //connect source to speakers so we can hear it
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true); 
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; //the  response is an array of bits
    request.onload = function() {
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(response) {
            source.buffer = response;
            source.start(0); //play audio immediately
            source.loop = true;
        }, function () { console.error('The request failed.'); } );
    }
    request.send();
}
```